Remove and blacklist [.net-core-5] tag synonym for [.net-5]
Previously it was decided to synonym-ise .net-core-5 with .net-5. But there is no such thing as ".NET Core 5.0", and the presence of a synonym for something that doesn't exist is both confusing and wrong; therefore .net-core-5 should be removed as a synonym, and blacklisted so people who don't understand how .NET versioning works in a post-Framework post-Core world, are unable to bring this tag back from the dead.

merging the tags might be the simpler option, not sure if it will truly pop up again, considering you need sufficient reputation to create new tags (2000 I think?)

@Lino the merge already happened

Blacklisting isn't something regularly done1, and the synonym already prevents usage of .net-core-5.
If anything I'd say the synonym supports the notion that ".NET Core 5.0" is not a thing of it's own.
So no, the synonym should not be removed as it prevents the wrong .net-core-5 from being created and redirects their uses to the proper tag.

1) As far as I understand this is because the performance impact scales with number of blacklisted tags and it's not a very performant system to begin with.

It's one giant regex, as far as I know.
